# DS3231 with Arduino Nano for Timing precision

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-mega, interrupt, timers, rtc

I am in need to synchronize two separate circuit boards working with Arduino nano. The need is to activate one relay using Arduino-1 after 45 min and another relay using Arduino-2 after 45.36 seconds. The time starts from the point of reception of input from an external switch common to both.

with ref to [This question](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/91915/arduino-nano-timing-precision) and from the advice of [edgar-bonet](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/users/7508/edgar-bonet) I have used one temperature-compensated RTC for timing the Arduino s externally **(DS3231)**. I am using its 32kHz pin from the chip for counting the ticks and in the Arduino using the interrupt to count the ticks.

The program is shown below.

```
float _sec = 1;


float secTime =  _sec * 1000UL; // second->millis
uint32_t coilTime = 5 * 1000UL; // second->millis

volatile uint32_t count = 0;
/*
 * 32768 ticks in 1 sec
 * 0.032768 tick in 1 us
 */

float _multiplier = 0.032768; // 32768 Hz

uint32_t _delay = secTime * _multiplier * 1000UL ;

volatile bool onFlag = false;

ISR(INT1_vect, ISR_NOBLOCK) {
  count = count + 1UL;
  if (_delay == count) {
    PORTC |= (1 << 5);
    onFlag = true;
    EIMSK = 0;
  }
}

ISR(INT0_vect) {
  /* INTERRUPT re-initalization */
  EIMSK = 0;
  EICRA = B00001100; // INT0 - clear ; INT1 -  set
  EIFR  = 0;
  PORTB ^=  (1 << 0) | (1 << 1); // setting Green off and red on
  count = 0;
  EIMSK = B00000010; // INT0 - inactive ; INT1 - active
} 


void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);

  /* PIN initialization */
  DDRB |= (1 << 0) | (1 << 1); // red led and green led

  pinMode(3, INPUT_PULLUP); // timer unit
  pinMode(2, INPUT); // interrupt unit

  DDRC |= (1 << 3) | (1 << 4) | (1 << 5); // relay, OUT_1, OUT_2

  /* LEDs state update */
  PORTB &=  ~(1 << 1); // red off.
  PORTB |= (1 << 0); // green on.

  PORTC &= ~(1 << 3); // A3-off

  /* INTERRUPT initalization */
  EICRA = B00000011; // INT0 - set ; INT1 - not set
  EIMSK = B00000001; // INT0 - active ; INT1 - inactive
  EIFR  = 0;
}

void loop() {



  if (onFlag) {

    PORTB |= (1 << 0); // setting green on

    delay(500);
    PORTC ^= (1 << 5);
    //    PORTB ^= (1 << 0) | (1 << 1);
    PORTB ^= (1 << 1); // setting red off
    while (true) {
      TCCR2B = 0;
      count = 0;
      PORTB ^= (1 << 0);
      delay(500);
    }
  }
}
```

when running the program The result I am expecting the accuracy of microseconds
but

for
input -> Measured value
1 sec -> 1.000387792
2 sec -> 2.000784208
50 sec -> 50.020926833
250 sec -> 250.104557792

How to make the clock more precise, In the datasheet it is said that the clock is accurate to +- 2ppm.

[datasheet-ds3231](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/DS3231.pdf)

Comment: I'm not completely sure I understand your use case because, at least for the initial synchronisation, there is a connection between the 2 devices.
`volatile uint32_t count . . . count = 0;` beware of asynchronous non-atomic operations on multi-byte variables on an 8bit MCU. For high precision calculations, float may have limitations: `float _multiplier = 0.032768;` 2ppm is about one second every five days.

Comment: Can you please advise me on the correct variables to be used? In the initial case, I have a common switch connected to my devices and I use that as the interrupt signal.

Comment: `1.0000000 / (1.000387792 / 32768 ) = 32755.29776` .... that makes 32755 ticks in 1 second

Comment: `after 45 min and another relay using Arduino-2 after 45.36 seconds` does not declare the necessary precision ... for example, 45.36 can be anywhere between 44.355000... and 45.364999...

Comment: @jsotola, If i am okay with that much dispersion what modifications to be done.?

Comment: Instead of using floats to specify the time interval,  why not  specify say 1 second as 32768? At a quick glance, the loss of ticks (in comparison to your reference) seems linear at around 13 per second. Maybe try switching off timer 0 to inhibit its possibly clashing interrupts and then you'll have to find another solution for delay().

Comment: 1. I cannot understand what your code is trying to do, and I do not see how the code relates to the “input -> measured value” part of the question. I suggest you follow the advice in [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). 2. You have a very contrived way of writing `_delay = 32768`. Please, note that `0.032768` cannot be represented as a float, and will be rounded to the nearest representable number, which is 0.0327679999172687530517578125

Answer (score 1):

This may not be a proper answer to your question. Instead of telling you
how to improve the accuracy, I will show you how to measure it. The
issue is that the code you posted is doing too much stuff, and it is not
clear how it could be measuring the clock accuracy. So, instead I
suggest you try the code below:

- connect a push button between pin 2 and GND
- connect the 32768 Hz signal to pin 5
- watch the built-in LED blink

```cpp
const uint8_t input_pin = 5;  // 32768 Hz on digital 5 = T1
const uint8_t clear_pin = 2;  // button to clear timer

void setup() {
    pinMode(input_pin, INPUT_PULLUP);
    pinMode(clear_pin, INPUT_PULLUP);
    pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);

    // Configure Timer 1 as a counter.
    TCCR1A = 0;
    TCCR1B = _BV(CS11) | _BV(CS12);  // count falling edges of T1
}

void loop() {
    // Display bit 14 of the counter on the builtin LED.
    if (TCNT1 & (1 << 14)) {
        digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);
    } else {
        digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);
    }

    // Clear the counter on button press.
    if (digitalRead(clear_pin) == LOW) {
        TCNT1 = 0;
    }
}
```

What this sketch does is use Timer/counter 1 as a counter in order to
count the falling edges of the 32768 Hz signal. Bit 14 of the counter
should then toggle at 1 Hz. This bit is output on the built-in LED to
let you check its frequency. You can use the push button to reset the
phase of the blinks.

If you have a very accurate clock at hand, you can use the push button
to synchronize the blinks with the ticks of that clock, and then see how
long it takes to get visibly out of phase. You can also synchronise the
blinks of two Arduinos and see for how long they stay in sync. If you
have a scope, you could measure a tiny offset between the edges of the
two Arduino's LEDs, then see how this offset evolves with time.